# WKWebViewEngine only show blank screen when combined with cordova-plugin-mfp

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is there any cordova MFP user here?

I've tried to combine plugin cordova-plugin-ionic-wkwebview-engine^1.1.4 with cordova-plugin-mfp@8.0.2019082207 but only come up with blank screen.

I already tried cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine prior cordova-plugin-ionic-wkwebview-engine and got the same result.

I also tried to googling the issue but only come up with this APAR
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PH14091

where the explanation is only:

```
"The problem was fixed by handling the page load in the
cordova-plugin-mfp"
```

which I don't understand because there's no step provided. please help me guys.

Do let me know if there any screenshot need to be provided

Answer (score 1):

The plugins `cordova-plugin-ionic-wkwebview-engine` and `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` are different.

The former is added when you create an Ionic project and the latter can be added to any Cordova project. There could be Ionic project specific code in the `cordova-plugin-ionic-wkwebview-engine` plugin which could be preventing the launch screen from being displayed.

Switch over to the root plugin `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine`

The APAR you mentioned in your question is a fix for the `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` and not the Ionic version of the plugin

Comment: thank you for the answer, i already tried cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine prior cordova-plugin-ionic-wkwebview-engine and got the same result, that's why i switch to cordova-plugin-ionic-wkwebview-engine.. i will update the description.